# Sending hierarchical NSDictionary as POST request

Tags: api, post, encoding, nsdictionary, nsurlrequest

I've got method that converts `NSDictionary`s to POST argument strings for sending to an API we use in an app we're working on. It properly converts `NSString`s, `NSDate`s and `NSArray`s. That works just fine.

Now I've got a situation where one of the objects in my dictionary might actually be another dictionary and I was wondering how to handle that in terms of the POST request. How do you guys handle hierarchical data structures? I thought of sending multiple requests for each dictionary but I'm not sure if there's not a better way.

Thanks
-f

Comment: Does the POST request have to send its data as a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" type? Can you use JSON instead?

Comment: Since we're doing the API on our own I think we can change that. So what you basically mean is to generate a JSON string from my dictionary structure and append that as the POST argument?

Comment: Personally, I would just "JSONify" the entire NSDictionary as a string and send that as HTTP request body with a Content-Type: application/json without further encoding it. However, as you suggested, you could convert the value as a JSON structure to send as an argument; one potential drawback is that it could involve a lot of encoding/decoding depending on what type of data you send.

Comment: The way you described it works nicely. Thank's a lot! I just did not have in mind that I could replace the whole old key-value POST string with a nice JSON one. So how can I mark your comment as the best answer? Post it again and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would just "JSONify" the entire NSDictionary as a string and send that as HTTP request body with a Content-Type: application/json without further encoding it. However, as you suggested, you could convert the value as a JSON structure to send as an argument; one potential drawback is that it could involve a lot of encoding/decoding depending on what type of data you send.